# Assigning data to dictionary not existing key causes error

Tags: python

When creating dictionary can't assign data if key was not created e.g.

```
dct = {}
dct['main']['sub'] = 'Hello World'
```

workaround is always need to create empty key

```
dct = {}
dct['main'] = {}
dct['main']['sub'] = 'Hello World'
```

Any way to switch off this behavior of Python so following line of code will create with two sub keys rather than cause error?

```
dct['main']['sub'] = 'Hello World'
```

Comment: No you can't "switch off" core Python functionality, but per the dupe there are alternatives.